# Problem about factor and abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

a) Show that a factor group of an abelian group is abelian
b) Show that a factor group of a cyclic group is cyclic

Approach: a) Let G be an abelian group and $G/N$ be the factor group of G. Let $aN,bN \in G/N$ for $a,b \in G$, so we have to show that

$$(aN)(bN)=(bN)(aN)$$

$$(aN)(bN)=(Na)(bN)=N(ab)N$$

and we know that G is abelian so,

$$N(ab)N=N(ba)N=(Nb)(aN)=(bN)(aN)$$

How does that look?. The book does the following step in a very natural way, but why can we do it?

$$(Na)(bN)=N(ab)N$$

Approach part b) if G is cyclic then $G=<t>$ for some $t \in G$, so we have show that $\forall aN\in G/N$ where $a\in G$, $aN=t^r$ for some $r\in Z$.

We can clearly represent a in the form $t^r$, but what about N?. what do we do with it?

Comment: Say $G = \{ t^0, t, \ldots, t^{n - 1} \}$. Then $G / N = \{ N, tN, \ldots, t^{n - 1} N \}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a)$ No, we don't multiply $Na$ by $bN$. Remember that the operation of the factor group is $(aN)(bN)=abN$. Then, since $G$ is abelian, $(aN)(bN)=abN=baN=(bN)(aN)$, for all $a,b\in G$.

$b)$ If $a=t^r$ then $aN=t^rN=(tN)^r$.